# how to intergrate NPI lookup?

Tags: jquery, ajax

There's a site called NPI registry lookup which will show the information about the doctor you're searching for. 
i am getting this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=1306935523. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58202' is therefore not allowed access.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {              
                $('#btnGetNpi').click(function () {                                 
                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        url: 'https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=' + $('#txtnpi').val(),
                        method: 'get',                       
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            resultElement.html('FirstName:' + data.basic[0].first_name);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                            alert(exception);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: thats a cross domain issue. do you control the server?

Comment: This is third party API we do not have control over server we need pas only input and get output in the form of JSON

Comment: Hi Puja,  Did you ever figure this one out?  I have the exact same problem using the HHS API.

Comment: Still a problem in 2019.  There was an attempt by someone to provide an updated goverment access point, but it is not funded so we are stuck with calling the API from the server side and sending the resulting JSON back to the browser, which isn't too awful.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue and had to hack a solution. This is by no means a final or permanent solution, but it does work. I am going to attempt to contact whoever maintains this database and let them know that it is CORS blocked and as such a useless public API, hopefully, we can get that changed.

Here is what I ended up doing:
n.b. You may not have php, but I'm willing to bet some other languages have something similar that could work.

.js file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:  'somefile.php',
    data: 'npiNumber=xxxxxxxxxx',
    success: function(response) {
        var npiData = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(npiData);
    }
});
```

.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['npiNumber'])) {
    echo file_get_contents('https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/resultsDemo2/?number='.$_POST['npiNumber']);
}
```

That's all. The php file_get_contents literally goes to the page and loads it and returns the content of whatever is on that page. It isn't a server request so much as just a "give me the results of the page itself" request. Then I pass that back to javascript and parse it into a JSON object. Ugly hack. Ugly.

Comment: Did you ever contact them about changing the CORS policy?

Comment: @NeilVanLandingham I did. I never heard back. Maybe I should look into that again... or some other person at the department. Because that's kind of a major issue.

Comment: .NET has a similar solution.  I just posted a response back to my server, loaded it from the server, and sent the JSON string back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the US Gov has a free API for doing NPI lookups, so you could pull your code from here:  https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/
It has a link to the API, which shows how to request info from the NPI db.  There are several other websites that do this too, so you could crib code from them....

> Application Programming Interface (API) | Read-Only The API is a new,
>   faster alternative to the downloadable NPPES data files. It allows
>   systems to access NPPES public data in real-time, rather than through
>   batched uploads. The API retrieves data from NPPES daily.
>
> NPPES Read API Interactive Test Application System administrators can
>   use the interactive demo to experiment with generating queries. The
>   API will generate its output at https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/.

There are several sites that do NPI lookups.  Look at their code.  Other sites do it.  Copy the successful ones.

Those of you who are coders should be able to make this sing!

Comment: This is the same API to which the question is referring. Although it appears to be documented well, it sadly seems to be blocked by a CORS policy that renders it largely useless to the general public.